# XML Deserialization : from xmlString to complex class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, class, deserialization

This is the xml what I get from database:

> ```
> > <Library>
> >     <Header>
> >         <HeaderID>01</HeaderID>
> >     </Header>
> >     <Books>
> >         <Book>
> >             <Name>Book1</Name>
> >             <Category>Fiction</Category>
> >             <Authors>2</Authors>
> >         </Book>
> >         <Book>
> >             <Name>Book2</Name>
> >             <Category>Non - Fiction</Category>
> >             <Authors>1</Authors>
> >         </Book>
> >      </Books>
> >      <Authors>
> >           <Author>
> >               <Name>Author1ForBook1</Name>
> >           </Author>
> >           <Author>
> >               <Name>Author2ForBook1</Name>
> >           </Author>
> >           <Author>
> >               <Name>Author1ForBook2</Name>
> >           </Author>
> >       </Authors> 
> ></Library>
> ```

This is my class:

```
public class Library
{
   public Header header{get; set;}
   public List<Book> books{get;set;}
   public List<Author> authors{get;set;}
}

public class Header
{
   int ID{get;set;}
}

public class Book
{
  string Name{get; set;}
  string Category{get; set;}
  string Fiction{get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
  string Name{get;set;}
}
```

What I want to be able to do is, to deserialize the xml string I get from database into the class object - Library. Currently I am using the following code to it, but I get an error:

```
String xData = RequestXml;
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Library));
Library myTest = (Library)x.Deserialize(new StringReader(xData));
```

The error I get is:

There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

Comment: Consider posting actual value of `RequestXml` instead of what you think value should be.

Comment: post the full exception

Comment: Your example works as-is for me.  All I had to do was change the casing of your properties and make them public and it deserialized perfectly.

Comment: Of course, that assumes that the extra ">" characters in your XML are artifacts and not part of the actual text... Because if they are, well, I think you've found your problem.

Comment: when I tried to change all the variable to public. This is working fine. Although, deserializing does not populate the value in myTest.

Comment: So, basically I cannot get the value for Library.Header.ID. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your comments in the Question.

> basically I cannot get the value for Library.Header.ID. How can I achieve it?

because it's `Library.Header.HeaderID` and not `Library.Header.ID`.. your property is named `ID`..

Use and define **Data Annotations** on your properties to map elements

```
 using System.Xml.Serialization;

 public class Header
 {
   [XmlElement(DataType = "integer", ElementName = "HeaderID")]
   int ID{get;set;}
 }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: note, `DataType = "integer" ` and `DataType = "int"` in the remarks section of the msdn link. The problem I see is that you're xml snippet has **01**.. I'm not sure whether you should be parsing or not..

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article. You can autogenerate everything you need, so you don't have to hand code it andmake mistakes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2011/05/14/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe.aspx

Comment: The reason I am handcoding is because I do not want an array...and when I use xsd it automatically makes my List<class> as an array.

Answer (score 1):

My new class looks like this and works like a charm:

```
 [XmlRoot("Library")]
    public class Library
    {
         [XmlElement("Header")]
        public Header header { get; set; }
         [XmlElement("Book")]
        public List<Book> books { get; set; }
         [XmlElement("Author")]
        public List<Author> authors { get; set; }
    }


    public class Header
    {

        public int HeaderID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Fiction { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
       public  string Name { get; set; }
    }
```